# customer_register_success not triggered when customer register using social login

Tags: event-observer

I want to create an observer after a successful registration. customer_register_success not trigger when customer register using social login

Comment: magento does not have social login default. You have using 3rd party modules?

Comment: yes mageplaza social login.  @AmitBera

Answer (score 0):

In mageplaza login controller add code for dispatch "customer_register_success " event

**How to dispatch events?**

```
namespace Vendor\Extension\Controller\Index;

class Myevent extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    public function execute()
    {
        $nameobj = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(array('name' => 'Magecomp'));
        $this->_eventManager->dispatch('gohil_customevent_update_name', ['obj' => $nameobj]);
        //$this->_eventManager this object has already created in Action Class so don’t need to create again.
        echo $textDisplay->getText();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Thank you. @Gohil Rajesh